# Getting error ORA-00918 when using match_recognize

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Am trying to learn the Pattern matching that was introduced with Oracle 12c. However getting the ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
  with from the below code. Am not sure where i missed it

```
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,ORDER_TOTAL,ORDER_TIMESTAMP FROM DEMO_ORDERS MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
  ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID,ORDER_TIMESTAMP

  MEASURES
   A.CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER,
    A.ORDER_TOTAL AS TOTAL_AMT,
    A.ORDER_TIMESTAMP AS WHEN_HPA
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN( A B* )
  DEFINE
    B AS (B.ORDER_TOTAL < PREV(B.ORDER_TOTAL))


    )
```

Comment: There are a few other problems with this code (besides what Alex pointed out already). In MEASURES you include only A.CUSTOMER_ID etc., but you return ALL ROWS PER MATCH. If you want to return the respective values for each row, don't measure A.CUSTOMER_ID, measure CUSTOMER_ID. And then, use the column aliases from MEASURES in  SELECT. (You used the original column names from the base table, which is just as well because in MEASURES you didn't define any new expressions, you just renamed existing columns). If you just want to return existing columns, you don't need to include MEASURES at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `order by` clause; it seems to be seeing the original table column `customer_id` and the match partition value at the same time.

But a you're partitioning by `customer_id`, so ordering by that doesn't make any sense anyway. The ordering applies within the partition (as in analytic functions). So you can just remove that:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,ORDER_TOTAL,ORDER_TIMESTAMP FROM DEMO_ORDERS MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
  ORDER BY ORDER_TIMESTAMP
...
```